# Why do we need to include !packages/*.targets in .tfignore when excluding NuGet packages from source control

Tags: tfs, nuget

The [NuGet documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore) on excluding packages from TFS is to do the following

```
## Ignore the NuGet packages folder in the root of the repository
packages

#include package target files which may be required for msbuild
!packages/*.targets
```

Does anybody know why we need to include .targets ?

Answer (score 0):

The real reason: because someone didn't copy the .targets file to the project.

The problem it's trying to solve: You can't load a project in a solution if the targets file it references can't be found.

So this feels pretty much like a workaround to allow you to open the project and to then update the nuget packages. A better solution would have been that the NuGet package copies the .targets file to the project directory or at least uses a trick to include a bootstrapper in the project so the project can load without issues.

Comment: So is best practice to cut/copy the .targets file from any nuget package and add them to each project that uses it? That seems more overhead?

Comment: That is something the nuget package could do itself using an install script. So best would be to contact the author.